# Parse xml data using T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

`DECLARE @xml xml` SET @xml = `'<row Col1='abc' Col2='def' Col3='123' />`
`<row Col1='aaa' Col2='bbb' Col3='111'/>`

I need SQL Query to extract Col1, Col2, Col3 values. I don't know how to do that since the data is not in traditional format as below

`<row>`
`<col1>'abc'</col1>`
`<col2>'def'</col2>`
`<col3>'123'</col3>`
`</row>`

Also, I apologize but I'm having hard time posting the details due to formatting issues with body of the message. StackOverflow is not simple for first time user and people who are new coding.

MS SQL Server 2012 or later.

Thanks.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Show what you have tried so far and (presumably) your question will be about the code you have that's not working.

Comment: There is no need for any parsing. SQL Server supports XML data type and XQuery.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky since the data is not in a typical xml format I'm unable to figure out node to use in XQuery. I was hoping to get some assistance in terms how to extract the values associated with Col1 and Col2 via t-sql query. Thanks.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

A *minimal reproducible example* is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
('<row Col1="abc" Col2="def" Col3="123"/>'),
('<row Col1="aaa" Col2="bbb" Col3="111"/>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , c.value('@Col1', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Col1
    , c.value('@Col2', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Col2
    , c.value('@Col3', 'INT') AS Col3
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/row') AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------------------------------+------+------+------+
| ID |                 xmldata                  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------------------------------------------+------+------+------+
|  1 | <row Col1="abc" Col2="def" Col3="123" /> | abc  | def  |  123 |
|  2 | <row Col1="aaa" Col2="bbb" Col3="111" /> | aaa  | bbb  |  111 |
+----+------------------------------------------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! This works. Appreciate all your help.